# python - Filter JSON to a new JSON object

Tags: python, json

I have a json object which I would like to filter for misspelled key name. So for the example below, I would like to have a json object without the misspelled test_name key. What is the easiest way to do this?

```
json_data = """{
    "my_test": [{
        "group_name": "group-A",
        "results": [{
            "test_name": "test1",
            "time": "8.556",
            "status": "pass"
        }, {
            "test_name": "test2",
            "time": "45.909",
            "status": "pass"
        }, {
            "test_nameZASSD": "test3",
            "time": "9.383",
            "status": "fail"
        }]
    }]
}"""
```

This is an online test, and looks like i'm not allowed to use jsonSchema.

So far my code looks like this:

```
if 'test_suites' in data:
    for suites in data["test_suites"]:
        if 'results' in suites and 'suite_name' in suites:
            for result in suites["results"]:
                if 'test_name' not in result or 'time' not in result or 'status' not in result:                        
                    result.clear()                        
                else:
                    ....
        else:
            print("Check 'suite_name' and/or 'results'")
else:
    print("Check 'test_suites'")
```

It kind of works, but result.clear() leaves a empty {}, which get annoying later. What can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data have a consistent schema. So I would try using [json schema](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema) to solve your problem. With that you can set up a schema and only allow objects with certain key names.

If you just want to check if a certain key is in the dictionary and make sure that you only get the ones that are according to spec you could do something like this:

```
passed = []
for item in result:
    if 'test_name' in item.keys():
        passed.append(item)
```

But if you have a lot of different keys you need to check for it will become unwieldy. So for bigger projects I would say that json schema is the way to go.

Comment: I'll take look at that. 
Right now I'm checking the json, and if i find anything wrong, I'm doing results.clear(). (only for that last set)
But still leaves the {} brackets. How can I tackle this?

Comment: @tsf144 I added a way how you could do it.

Comment: I added my code so far. It is kind of getting messy, but I'm not allowed to use jsonSchema it seems.

Comment: Not allowed to use jsonschema? By whom?

Comment: it's an online test, and i'm allowed to submit only one file. Unless I totally misunderstood how it works. But it errors out to 'No module named 'jsonschema'